# Adding a pop up confirmation message after all data in a column has been recorded

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I am new to google script and I am trying my best to make modification to the "write once" script that I found from the web. Currently, I am working on a spreadsheet that keeps a record of lab equipment readings such as temperature, humidity, etc. For this spreadsheet, the first row is going the day of the month, so B1 is day 1 and AF1 is day 31. The first column contains the list of what needed to be recorded, ie. like temperature, humidity; so A2:A12.  All the readings are going to be recorded in B2:AF12. Row 14 is where the technician who did the recording of the readings will put his/her initial. For example on day 1 of that month, the tech will put the initial on B14.

Below is the script that I have with some modification. Problem with this script is that every time a reading is entered a pop-up message will appear asking to confirm the value. Instead of that, I wanted the message to appear at the end after the tech who collects the reading for that day put down his/her initial. I wanted the pop up to say something like "Please confirm all the readings! These readings cannot be changed once confirmed". If selected yes, then all the readings of that day as well as the initial will be stored on the helper sheet and the active sheet. If selected no, then nothing will be stored on the helper sheet. The tech will go back and correct the errors (typo with one of the reading). After making sure everything is correct, the tech will initial again and select yes for the confirmation popup.

```
   function onEdit() {
var firstDataRow = 2; // only take into account edits on or below this row
var lastDataRow = 14; // only take into account edits on or above this row
var firstDataColumn = 2; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column
var lastDataColumn = 32; // only take into account edits on or to the left of this column
// naming pattern for sheets where values are copied for later checking
var helperSheetNameSuffix = "_helper";
// sheets that are free to edit with no protection
var freeToEditSheetNames = ["Free to edit 1", "Free to edit 2",   helperSheetNameSuffix + "$"];
// You can use regular expressions in sheet names. The match is not case-sensitive,
// so "free.*edit" will match "free to edit", "Free Editing for Everyone", 
// "Sheet (free to edit)" and "Free edit playground".
// Leave the last entry, helperSheetNameSuffix + "$", as it is to ensure that changes to a
// helper sheet do not trigger the creation of another _helper_helper sheet.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var masterSheetName = masterSheet.getName();
var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
var sheetNameRegExp;
// do not record edits on free to edit sheets
for (var sheet in freeToEditSheetNames) {
sheetNameRegExp = new RegExp(freeToEditSheetNames[sheet], "i");
if (sheetNameRegExp.test(masterSheetName)) return;
} 
// find helper sheet
var helperSheetName = masterSheetName + helperSheetNameSuffix;
var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
if (helperSheet == null) { // helper sheet does not exist yet, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
helperSheet = ss.insertSheet(helperSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
ss.setActiveSheet(masterSheet);
helperSheet.hideSheet();
ss.setActiveRange(masterCell);
}
if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() <    firstDataColumn || masterCell.getRow() > lastDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() > lastDataColumn) return;
var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
var newValue = masterCell.getValue(); 
var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('Is This Entry Correct?', 'This cell cannot be changed after entering a value', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
if (response == ui.Button.YES && oldValue == "") {
masterCell.setValue(newValue);  
helperCell.setValue(newValue);
} 
if (response == ui.Button.YES && oldValue !== "") {
masterCell.setValue(oldValue); Browser.msgBox('You can not change this value. Please make corrections under Comment & Date/Initial');
}
if (response ==ui.Button.NO && oldValue == "") {
Browser.msgBox('Please Enter A New Value!'); masterCell.setValue("");  return
}  
if (response ==ui.Button.NO && oldValue !== "") {
masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide us a sample of your sheet ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1agb9d9MxC7veXlz2ReWQapKmfhLcDMa_gOuebarYbgQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please follow the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a function with the OnEdit() feature your spreadsheet will continuously run the script every time you enter or change a value.

Therefore, a cleaner way would be using a popup msg box when the user has inserted all the values inside a new function:

```
function submitvalues(){
    var sheet = spreadSheetApp.getActive().getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var question = Browser.msgBox('Is This Entry Correct?', 'This cell cannot be changed after entering a value', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);

if(question  == 'no'){


//etc. etc.}
}
```

However, it is easier now to either make a button where you assign this bit of the script to or to make a new menu item next to the help button by doing this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Update')
      .addItem('Update All Data', 'submitvalues')

      .addToUi();
}
```

Another tip to simplify your script would be to loop through the submitted values in mastersheet and write those as an array in helpersheet. You can then check within that array if any of the cells are empty and return an errorbox. You then don't have to create all the variables you currently have.

**EDIT:**
Just an example that you have to adapt to fit your script, insert this in the pervious submitvalues function at the end when you have done your first submitbox messages:

```
var val = mastersheet.getRange(2,sheet.getLastColumn(),12,1).getValues(); // this will take the data in the last column where you have just added the new data for 12 rows

for (var i=0;i<val.length;i++){ //this is where you start the loop
if (val[i]==""){
Browser.msgBox('Not all values are inserted, please return and insert all values')
return}// this is where you stop the function when the if statement is false
}
helpersheet.getRange(start row, start column, val.length,val[0].length).setValues(val); //this is where you set your values from the mastersheet
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Google script or programming in general is something that I just pick up last week so a lot of the concepts are still very new to me. Is possible that you can show me how to do a loop through the submitted values in the mastersheet and write those as an array to the helpersheet or an example of how to do a loop. Thanks

Comment: Have just edited my first answer with the loop. Hope this helps, don't forget to upvote and if this is the answer you  are looking for please press the answered button

Answer (score 0):

The script use the reserved word onEdit which is used for a on edit simple trigger.

If you do/don't want that something occurs every time that a edit occurs, then you should add a [JavaScript statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) like if..else, switch, or something similar.